# Divide Set of numbers to sequence? Find General Term?

Tags: algorithm, sequence

How can we divide set of numbers to sequence? And find the general term?

1 - numbers are always in order

2 - if we have n numbers n/2 numbers are always present

For example we have:

```
Input: 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30
Output--> 2*X, x=[0..15]
```

OR

```
Input: 0,2,4,5,6,8,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30
```

Divide into two set

```
A: 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30

B: 5,10,15,20

Output--> 2*X, x=[0..15] AND 5*X, x=[1..4]
```

I think this is very difficult, any comments?

What computer field or algorithm can help me?

Comment: huh.... are you ok with lieutenant term? 'cause i found him.

Comment: if the sequences are always a x, then it's easy.  if they are totally unconstrained, then there is no (unique) solution.

Comment: please be more specific: what kind of "term" are you interested in ? which look like a*x ? like some progression ? if there's no constraint the only thing you can try is to lookup http://oeis.org/ someway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I understand it is this:  Given a sequence of numbers, find the set of sequences that start from zero and increase by a constant multiple which cover this set.

Here's a general outline of what I would do:

I would make a list of all the numbers in the set, and iterate through starting from the first two elements to generate all of the possible sets meeting your criteria which are here.  If you encounter an element in the list, you can remove it from consideration as a generating number since any list with that number as a constant multiple is a subset of a list you've encountered before.  When you are done you will have a list of possible sets you can use to cover that set.  FOR EXAMPLE:

0,2,4,5,6,8,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30

We will start with 0 and 2.  We'll look for elements that are successively 2 larger and remove them from the list of elements that will be considered as possible multiples.  Once we find a multiple of 2 that's not in this list, we'll stop generating.  Here we go:

```
s(2) = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30]
```

Which leaves:

```
[5,15]
```

as the two potential other candidates.  Do you see that any of the elements, eg, 4, which are divisible by two will make subsets of that list and thus don't need to be considered?

The remaining list in the set will start at 0 and increase by 5, our smallest element:

[0,5,10,15,20]

(Remember we are checking the original list for these multiples and not the truncated list- the truncated list is only the list of remaining candidates.  When the candidate list is empty we know we will have found all of the sets which are contained in this set who have no supersets.

For a more complex example:

[0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 15]

We'll start with:

```
[0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14]
```

Which leaves
    [3 5 7 9 13 15]

as candidates, which in turn generates:

```
[0 3 6 9 12 15]
```

which leaves

```
[5 7 13]
```

which generates

```
[0 5 10 15]
```

which leaves

```
[7 13]
```

which generates

```
[0 7 14]
```

which leaves

```
[13]
```

which generates

```
[0 13].
```

The total combination of sets is:

```
[0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14]
[0 3 6 9 12 15]
[0 5 10 15]
[0 7 14]
[0 13].
```

At this point, you have the smallest list of all of the sets needed to cover your set.  It should be trivial to generate the proper [0,1...n]/a*n descriptors from here.